# Alter Submit button of specific form

Tags: forms, hooks, 9

I am new to Drupal and want to alter a submit button of a node-edit form.
So I wrote a basic module to do so. And it also alters the form button of my form with the id=node_hotel_edit_form. But also it alters all submit buttons to the same text an classes, even in the backend.

My alter_hotel_form.info.yml

```
name: 'Alter Hotel Form'
type: module
description: 'Alters Hotel EDIT form'
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
package: 'Custom'
```

My alter_hotel_form.module

```
<?php

function alter_hotel_form_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  
  if ($form_id = 'node_hotel_edit_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'hotel-edit-submit btn btn-medium blue darken-2';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Save Hotel');

  }

}
```

Can anybody point me a direction or tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @Beebee - Thanks for answering. I wrote the above module to alter the classes and text of the submit button, of my form with the ID node_hotel_edit_form. But the hook alters EVERY submit button in front and backend, not only for the desired form ID.

Comment: Oh I see. You made a simple syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if ($form_id = 'node_hotel_edit_form')` is wrong. This will **assign** `node_hotel_edit_form` to `$form_id` and always evaluate to TRUE.

It should be `if ($form_id === 'node_hotel_edit_form')` or `==` also works.

Comment: Darn, I looked on that for hours now. You are absolutely right - Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, I once spent a whole day debugging js because I spelt `Drupal.behaviors` in British English: `Drupal.behaviours` :D

Comment: @арнонюм by the way, some people also write checks as `if ('node_hotel_edit_form' == $form_id)` so you won't make this mistake again. You'll get an error if you use a single `=` sign here.